# Message Transmission through rtpgstdepay event string not 0 terminated

Tags: gstreamer

When i depay the load using rtpgstdepay , I am getting warning message as

> event string is not 0 terminated.

How to resolve this problem?

```
pipeline : gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc ! queue ! rtpgstdepay ! autovideosink 


Warning :: "event string not 0 terminated"
Debug Info ::  gstrtpgstdepay.c(331): read_event (): /GstPipeline:Transporter/GstRtpGSTDepay:rtp_depay
```

Comment: can you please post exactly what warning messages you get (copy paste - maybe some lines around that one)

Comment: warning message "Event String Not 0 Terminated"

Debug Info :: gstrtpgstdepay.c(331): read_event (): /GstPipeline:Transporter/GstRtpGSTDepay:rtp_depay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In rtpgstdepay caps event string should be terminated by '0-byte character(\0)' for new versions. For older versions it should be terminated by ';(Semicolon)'.

If the event string was not terminated properly then 'event string not 0-terminated' warning message will arise.

This condition was added to overcome fix buffer overread problems, and ensures we don't read a string past the end of the buffer.

The compatibility matrix is like:

- old pay -> old depay:

no change, with upgraded core it would not crash on certain malformed
input.

- old pay -> new depay:

new depay finds ; at end and parses the message. core change doesn't
matter.

- new pay -> old depay:

new depay puts extra 0 after string. old depay just parses and skips the
extra 0 byte (because it is included in the length). With new core, certain
malformed payloads are not crashing.

- new pay -> new depay:

new pay adds extra 0 after string, new depay checks for 0 and decodes. new
core will avoid certain buffer overreads.

Comment: so how exactly have yo resolved the problem? what pay/depay element did you use?

Answer (score 0):

By using rtpgstpay & rtpgstdepay components i successfully transmitted the modified buffer through udp over rtp.

At Receiver end,

in udpsrc caps, i added caps event string in caps which is of type G_TYPE_STRING.

the caps event string is fetched when i launch this pipeline using -v option.

That event string is used in udpsrc caps property of my C code.